# RecylerView does not list items in order when added dynamicly after 3rd item added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a button that says `ADD ITEM`.

Below there is a `RECYCLERVIEW`.

When you click on `ADD ITEM` it adds an `EDITVIEW` to the recycler view.  You type text in it, and then click on `ADD ITEM` again and it adds another `EDITVIEW` to the recyler view.

Everything is in the right order.

When you click on `ADD ITEM` for the 4th time, instead of adding at the 4th position, it adds at the 1st position and moves the previous 3 items down 1.

What could be causing this?

Main Activity

```
package com.app.bowling.animalsrecycler;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.sql.Types.NULL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements RemoveClickListner{
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerAdapter mRecyclerAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    Button btnAddItem;
    ArrayList<RecyclerData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
     EditText etTitle;
    String title = "";
    ImageView crossImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myList,this);


        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);

         etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);


        if (mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 || mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() == NULL){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ZERO ITEMS LISTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                title = etTitle.getText().toString();

 //               if (title.matches("")) {
 //                   Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "You did not enter a Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //                   return;
 //               }


                RecyclerData mLog = new RecyclerData();
//                mLog.setTitle(title);

                myList.add(mLog);
                mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(myList);
                etTitle.setText("");


                if (mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() + " Items Displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void OnRemoveClick(int index) {
        myList.remove(index);
        mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(myList);
    }
}
```

RecyclerAdapter

```
package com.app.bowling.animalsrecycler;

import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerItemViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<RecyclerData> myList;
    int mLastPosition = 0;
    private RemoveClickListner mListner;
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerData> myList,RemoveClickListner listner) {
        this.myList = myList;
        mListner=listner;
    }
    public RecyclerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerItemViewHolder holder = new RecyclerItemViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d("onBindViewHolder ", myList.size() + "");

        mLastPosition = position;
        holder.crossImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_circle_black_24dp);
        holder.etTitleTextView.setHint("Enter Player " + (position + 1));
        holder.etTitleTextView.requestFocus();
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return(null != myList?myList.size():0);
    }
    public void notifyData(ArrayList<RecyclerData> myList) {
        Log.d("notifyData ", myList.size() + "");
        this.myList = myList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public class RecyclerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView etTitleTextView;
        private ConstraintLayout mainLayout;
        public ImageView crossImage;
        public RecyclerItemViewHolder(final View parent) {
            super(parent);


            etTitleTextView = parent.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            etTitleTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                myList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setTitle(etTitleTextView.getText().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });



                    crossImage = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.crossImage);
            mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Position:" + Integer.toString(getPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            crossImage.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mListner.OnRemoveClick(getAdapterPosition()
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

RecyclerData

```
package com.app.bowling.animalsrecycler;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RecyclerData {
    String title;

    RecyclerView data;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public void setCrossImage(ImageView crossImage){
        setCrossImage(crossImage);
    }
}
```

RemoveClickLstner

```
package com.app.bowling.animalsrecycler;

public interface RemoveClickListner {
    void OnRemoveClick(int index);
}

Activity_Main
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:id="@+id/etTitle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem"
        android:text="Add Item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#dbfffe" />
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView_Item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_height="112dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:layout_width="273dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="122dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_wrapHeight="0"
            tools:layout_conversion_wrapWidth="0" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/crossImage"
            android:layout_width="136dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="273dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_wrapHeight="0"
            tools:layout_conversion_wrapWidth="0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code here or what u have done

Comment: It'll be grateful, If you paste your snippet here.

Comment: Just a note.  I added an editview to the left of the ADD ITEM button.  Just as a place holder.  When I click on ADD ITEM, get focus on EDITVIEW in recyclerview and add the text.  If I click on add button, when I get to adding it the 4th time it puts it position 0.  If I repeat the same thing but click on the EDITVIEW and then add items it works perfectyly fine and puts everything in the right order, from oldest to newest.  Don't understand the difference and why, as I will not have that EDITVIEW next to the ADD ITEMS BUTTON.

Comment: try to call mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position) after added value to your list.

Comment: Replace whcih snippet with what?

Comment: That item is getting added correctly. I think the problem is the value of edit text is moving to other items because of recycling. Maintain those values in your data list properly. Make changes in data list and notify. It should work.

Comment: It works beautifully if the focus is on the EDITVIEW outside of the recylcerview.  however I set focus on the newly created EDITVIEW in the recyclerview.  That is where the problem is, I don't know why it works for the first 3 adds and then the 4th one goes bezerk.  So if focus is outside of recylerview it works, if focus is on item in reclyerview it doesn't work after 3rd item added.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to replace your below snippet

```
myList.add(mLog);
mRecyclerAdapter.notifyData(myList);
etTitle.setText("");
```

Add this:

```
myList.add(mLog);
mRecyclerAdapter.addAll(myList);
mRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
etTitle.setText("");
```

Comment: There is no such thing as .addAll.  When I do that it wants me to create a method for it.

Comment: This is the solution but not sure how to implement it without doing it this way,  Create an EDITVIEW next to ADDBUTTON outside of recyclerview.  Make it not visible,  When you click on ADD BUTTON, lose focus on the EDITVIEW in the recyclerview and give it to the invisible EDITVIEW and then create the new EDITVIEW in recylerview.  Can you setfocus to an item that visible is set to no?   Or the solution could be when you click on the ADD BUTTON count elements in recylerview and manually set the position of the newly created EDITVIEW.

Comment: So I added the following code to the button click listener.  etTitle.requestFocus();  That is the EDITVIEW outside of the recylerview.  The problem with this solution is, in my final code I will not have the EDITVIEW outside of the recycler, only the add button.

Comment: UPDATE:  I started all over from scratch again.  I found out where the actual problem is by building an apk each step of the way.  Part of the issue is understanding where to put the textwatcher in the recyclerview at.  With my old code above aparently it does not go in the RECYCLERADAPTER under RecyclerItemViewHolder.  So where do I put the TextWatcher at?

Comment: Update:Put Textwatcher in the TitleAdapter.  And when setting the EDITTEXT on creation and in the textwatcher I use this:   holder.etTitleTextView.setText(myList.get(position).getTitle());  All works great.  I removed the onfocus, which now when you add an item it goes to the first item in the list.  If I put the requestfocus back on then it will go to the newly added EDIT TEXT.  Issue is when you add a new item ad it goes to the next line, the FOCUS goes to the first item in the list instead of the newest one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see your layout activity_main and recycler_view item because I have tried implementing your code with few twist and the code is working well please check the code below

https://github.com/muchbeer/StackOverflowRecyclerView

Please find the below Screen Shot

[image: a busy coder]

Kindy let me if this was your intended application

Comment: This is similiar to what I am going after.  However there is not editview, only an ADD BUTTON.  When ADD BUTTON is clicked it creates an EDITVIEW in the recyclerview and it gets focus so you can input the text that you want.  I found the issue just not sure how to correct it.  When you do this for the 4th time it creates an EDITVIEW in the recyclerview like it should but at position 0 and not position 3.  So I experimented and added an EDITVIEW like your example.  When you do the same thing, as long as the EDITVIEW next to add button has the focus it creates the EDITVIEW in position 3.